# No annotated method found, falling back to SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy

Tags: spring-integration, aggregate

I tried to create a single bean which combined the release strategy method and the aggregator method:

```
public class POJOSingleAggregatorStrategy{
  @Aggregator
  public Message spliceMessage(List<Message<?>> messages) {
    ...
  }

  @ReleaseStrategy
  public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup messageGroup) {
    ...
  }

}

<channel id="inputChannel"/>

<channel id="outputChannel"/>

<bean id="aggregatorStrategyBean" class="sample.POJOSingleAggregatorStrategy"/>

<aggregator id="completelyDefinedAggregator" input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel" send-partial-result-on-expiry="false" ref="aggregatorStrategyBean" method="spliceMessage"/>
```

Without config `release-strategy-method`, the program works well but it repors a warning:

```
No annotated method found; falling back to SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy, target:sample.POJOSingleAggregatorStrategy, methodName:null
```

After configured `release-strategy-method="canRelease"`, the program doesn't work and it reports an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to process message list`

Anybody knows how to avoid this warning? (Except for rewrite `ReleaseStrategyFactoryBean`)

Answer (score 0):

Strange indeed; we have a test case [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/integration/AnnotationAggregatorTests.java#L63) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/integration/AnnotationAggregatorTests-context.xml) that does the same thing and it works fine.

If you can post a simple test case that reproduces the issue, we can take a look.

You also need to provide the full stack trace for the `IllegalStateException`.